# Read the contents of each file into a separate list in Python

Tags: python, bash, list, glob

I would like to ready the contents of each file into a separate list in Python.  I am used to being able to do something similar with a bash for loop where I can say:

```
for i in file_path; do writing stuff; done
```

With glob I can load each of the files but I want to save the contents in a list for each file to use them for comparison purposes later without hardcoding the names and number of lists. This is how far I have gotten in python:

```
import sys
import glob
import errno

list_$name[] ##<this is not python

path = './dir_name/*'   
files = glob.glob(path)   
for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()


    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise
```

Is what I want to do even possible or do I have to use a shell script to process each file as a loop?

Comment: What kind of data is it, that you are reading and comparing?

Comment: What kind of comparison are you doing that you need lists of lines? Not sure how `for i in file_path; do writing stuff; done` equates to reading multiple files into lists

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham The question isn't really a bash question.  For brevity I just wanted a simple example to show that I could save the processed contents of several files in bash and did not know how to do this in python. sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @lhcgeneva in this case it is a string of integers

Comment: @badner, I was asking as I would be willing to bet there is a much better way to approach the problem bar reading every file into lists, how are the values being compared? Also `list(map(str.rstrip, f))` would give you a list of lines with the need for calling read and splitlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
import glob
import errno

list_$name[] ##<this is not python

path = './dir_name/*'   
files = glob.glob(path)

contents = []   
for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()
            contents.append (lines)


    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise

    # Your contents list will now be a list of lists, each list containing the contents of one file.
```

Comment: conceptually different than what I was thinking but definitely a fantastic solution that works!  Thank you!